# Entity Framework ignores Any clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm stuck in a problem with a linq to entity query.

I have 3 tables: `Transaction`, `Security` and `Prices`.

The navigation is the following: 
A transaction has one security which can have many prices

What I'm trying to do is get a transaction with the security info and all the prices which date is less that the transaction date.

The query I've written is this:

```
context.Transaction
  .Include("Security.Prices")
  .Where(transaction =>
       transaction.Security.Prices.Any(price => price.Date < transaction.Date))
  .ToList();
```

The result of this query isn't what I expect, foreach transaction i always get all the prices of the security and not just the prices that have a date that is smaller that the transaction date.

Anthor thing I've tried was to invert the query trying to get all the transaction for a security, filterning on the security code and a list of userid. but even this time the any filter was ignored

```
context.Security
  .Include("Transactions")
  .Where(security => security.Code == code)
  .Where(s => s.Transactions.Any(t => Ids.Contains(t.Id)))
  .ToList();
```

With this code I get all the transaction for a security made by all the users and not just the users in the Ids list.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with this query?

Comment: I'm not an EF expert by far, but wouldn't Include and Where work on different data and parts of the problem? The include says "Include this data for the transactions you return", and the Where says "I want these transactions". I would find it very odd if the where was magically applied to the include-part as well. The Where part only filters the *transactions*, not the prices.

Comment: In other words, you should get only the transactions that has a price dated before the transaction date, but you will get all the prices connected to the that transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Lasse comments, you're selecting all `Transaction`s that have *any* price with a date before the transaction date. The resultset will include *all* prices per transaction. You'll want to filter those by `Select()`in a new resultset:

```
context.Transaction
       .Include("Security.Prices")
       .Where(transaction =>
          transaction.Security.Prices.Any(price => price.Date < transaction.Date))
       .Select(t => new Transaction
       {
           // Only select prices before the given date
           Prices = t.Prices.Where(price => price.Date < transaction.Date),
           OtherProperty = t.OtherProperty,
           // etc...
       })
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you guys,
I gave another interpretation to the code I wrote, I thought that the it was going to do something like this:

    select * from Transactions t
    inner join Securities s on s.Isin = t.Isin
    inner join Prices p on p.Isin = s.Isin
    where p.Date < t.Date

but I was wrong...